# D3.js dispatch React event

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

In my axis, I am trying to dispatch a React event with a payload. When I console.log('item'), I get a pointer event logged. The dispatch has as payload: isTrusted (from the pointer event) instead of having the item property dispatched. Is this the correct way to trigger a dispatch event with D3.js?

```
axisGroup
        .selectAll('.tick')
        .data<BaseItemI>(itemsInDomain)
        .style('cursor', 'pointer')
        .on('click', function (item) {
          console.log('clicked', item);
          // dispatch.arguments = { type: SET_SELECTED_ITEM, payload: item };
          dispatch({
            type: SET_SELECTED_ITEM,
            payload: { item: item, baseItem: undefined }
          });
        });
```

I tried using the dispatch from D3 but it is confusing. Also tried using a callback function instead of an anonymous function and I get the same behaviour.

```
.on('click', (item) => {
          console.log('clicked', item);
          dispatch({
            type: SET_SELECTED_ITEM,
            payload: { item: item, baseItem: undefined }
          });
        });
```

Comment: Did you try to use an arrow function instead of anonymous function?

Comment: Yes, same issue

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to get the .on('click', () => {}) to work but I instead added an onClick to the g element that contains the axisRef.

```
<g
      ref={ref}
      style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
      onClick={() => {
        itemsInDomain.map((i) => {
          dispatch({
            type: SET_SELECTED_ITEM,
            payload: { item: i, baseItem: undefined }
          });
        });
      }}
    ></g>
```